# Proving (C^n, +, *, C)'s identity property

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I'm currently checking all vector space axioms for $\mathbb{C}^n$ over the field $\mathbb{C}$ and find myself struggling with proving the property mentioning the identity element. That's what I've got so far:
$$
\begin{align}
1\cdot\vec{v}
&=1\cdot\left(\begin{array}{ccc}v_1\\v_2\\\vdots\\v_n\end{array}\right)\\
&=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}1\cdot v_1\\1\cdot v_2\\\vdots\\1\cdot v_n\end{array}\right)\\
&=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}v_1\\v_2\\\vdots\\v_n\end{array}\right)\\
&=\vec{v}.
\end{align}
$$

whereby $\vec{v}\in\mathbb{C}^n$ and $v_i\in\mathbb{C}$ for all $i\in\mathbb{N}$. (Should I rename $1$ to $e$?)

I wrote as a side note that "The complex multiplication identity in the field $\mathbb{C}$ is $1+0i$, so basically $1$". However, there's a proof on [Proof Wiki](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Complex_Multiplication_Identity_is_One) demanding that "Let $\mathbb{C}_{\neq0}$ be the set of complex numbers without zero." Why is it necessary to exclude $0$? Besides that is there anything wrong with my proof or do you have any tips to improve mine? I'm not studying mathematics so I really have no one else to ask even if it doesn't seem to be a difficult question.

====================================================================

**That's how I was introduced to vector spaces in general:**

A vector space is a set $V$ (where elements of $V$ are called vectors) over the field $\mathbb{F}$ (where elements of $\mathbb{F}$ are called scalars) together with the operations of addition $V\times V\longrightarrow V$ and scalar multiplication $\mathbb{F}\times V\longrightarrow V$ satisfying the following properties:

(I) Commutativity, meaning $\vec{u}+\vec{v}=\vec{v}+\vec{u}$ for all $\vec{u},\vec{v}\in V$.

(II) Associativity, meaning $(\vec{u}+\vec{v})+\vec{w}=\vec{u}+(\vec{v}+\vec{w})$ and $(ab)\vec{v}=a(b\vec{v})$ for all $\vec{u},\vec{v},\vec{w}\in V$ and $a,b\in\mathbb{F}$.

(III) Additive identity, meaning there exists an element $\vec{0}\in V$ such that $\vec{0}+\vec{v}=\vec{v}$ for all $\vec{v}\in V$.

(IV) Additive inverse, meaning that for every $\vec{v}\in V$ exists an element $-\vec{v}\in V$ such that $\vec{v}+(-\vec{v})=\vec{0}$.

(V) Multiplication identity, meaning $1\vec{v}=\vec{v}$ for all $\vec{v}\in V$.

(VI) Distributivity, meaning $a(\vec{v}+\vec{w})=a\vec{v}+a\vec{w}$ and $(a+b)\vec{v}=a\vec{v}+b\vec{v}$ for all $\vec{v},\vec{w}\in V$ and $a,b\in\mathbb{F}$.

Comment: I think proof wiki is talking about $\mathbb{C}_{\neq 0}$ as a group under multiplication, not a field. Your proof is compeletely fine as it is.

Comment: Oh, that would make sense since that's how the algebraic structure field was defined.